# Saving ref to a User login

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm having a trouble to write a simple User and Tweet Schemas relation.
I created a middleware that will check a user token once he logged in. This is a token based authentication. The problem lies in the '/tweet' route section of how to save a tweet to a Logged in user.

schema.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var UserSchema = new Schema({
   name: String,
   username: { type: String, required: true, index: { unique: true }},
   password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
   level: String,
   tweet: [{
       type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tweet'
   }],
});

 var TweetSchema = new Schema({

    _creator: { type: Number, ref: 'User'},
    title: String,
    content: String
 });

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Tweet', TweetSchema);
```

api.js

let just assume that I have written '/login' route for log in a user and create a token above this middleware.

```
// The middleware for verifying user's token ( The user already login )

apiRouter.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // do logging
    console.log("Somebody just came to our app!");

    var token = req.body.token || req.param('token') || req.headers['x-access-token'];

    // check if token exist
    if(token) {

        jwt.verify(token, superSecret, function(err, decoded) {
            if(err) {
                res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate user' });
            } else {

                // if everything is good save request for use in other routes
                req.decoded = decoded;

                next();
            }
        });

    } else {
        res.status(403).send({ success: false, message: 'No token provided' });
    }
});

// another route for creating a tweet, in order to use this route, user's token must be verified.

apiRouter.route('/tweet')

    .post(function(req, res) {

        // The problem is I dont know how to get a user that just Login to create a tweet that will save in his user_tweet Schema.


            var tweet = new Tweet({
                _creator: ???,
                title: req.body.title,
                content: req.body.content
            });

            tweet.save(function(err) {
                if(err) res.send(err);
                res.json({ message: "New tweet has been added" });
            });
    });
```

Currently I'm having a trouble to create a tweet and saves it to a User that already log in and token has been verified. What should I write in '/tweet' route section to achieve my goal.

I'm trying to emulate a Twitter app for you guys information.

Comment: You have a incorrect type here: `_creator: { type: Number, ref: 'User'}`, should be `ObjectId`

Comment: In `_creator` field in the route handler you will include your authorized user, typically `req.user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're using to generate your tokens, but the standard practice is to encode the user id as part of the token. So when you decode the token, like you've done here:

req.decoded = decoded;

req.decoded it should contain the user id, which you can then use to look up the user and check their permissions, or in your case, you'd use it to create your tweet object.

So something like this:

```
// create a json webtoken
var token = jwt.sign({
  id = user._id,
  name: user.name,
  username: user.username
}, superSecret, {
  expiresInMinute: 1440
});
```

Then do:

```
var tweet = new Tweet({
  _creator: req.decoded.id,
  title: req.body.title,
  content: req.body.content
});
```

Comment: this is the code where I generate the token https://gist.github.com/kacak9229/713abdc561374d4463c6

Comment: How do i use that user id to create the tweet?

Comment: It does save in the Tweet Schema, but in the User Schema the tweet array is still empty? Im confused.

Comment: That's because you're just creating a new Tweet object, after you call .save(), on the success callback, you need to retrieve the user object, and insert whatever data you want into the tweets array (if that's what you want to do). Mongoose does not perform joins on different collections like you'd expect from a SQL ORM.

Comment: Should I actually insert the data to the tweets array? is it best practice? Let say i really want to insert it how would i do that?

Comment: It's neither bad or good practice. Be careful though, as documents are limited to 16MBs in mongo, so if you have a user with thousands of tweets you may run into issues. It is simple to update the array, just retrieve the user object using User.findOne({ _id: req.decoded.id }), call user.tweetArray.push(newTweet), and call .save()

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. One last question though, if you were me would you even bother to save it to the tweets array?

Comment: I wouldn't, since I don't see how it would be useful. You're already querying the object on every request to retrieve the user information, for authentication purposes. You'd only need 1 more query to get the user's tweets, which is perfectly fine. You also won't need to worry about your user objects become too big, which kills performance.